# Unable to get Gnome desktop after installing from CentOS 6.5 minimal

Tags: gnome, centos

I have just installed CentOS 6.5 minimal.  The reason I installed the minimal version is that the full version had ISOs of over 3GB each and my CD-RWs can only told about 750 MB.

I would like a graphical desktop.  I tried

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts
```

and they both ran without any errors.  However, when I tried to run the desktop using

```
sudo gdm
```

and it just hung in the command line.  When I tried

```
gdm
```

I got

```
** (gdm-binary:2164): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager: Connection "1.37" is not allowed to own the service "org.gnome.DisplayManager" due to security policies in the configuration file

 ** (gdm-binary:2164): WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out
```

Answer (score 7):

Try doing the following instead.

*Install Desktop Packages*

```
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" \
        "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

*optional GUI packages*

```
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Graphical Administration Tools"
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Internet Browser"
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "General Purpose Desktop"
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Office Suite and Productivity"
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Graphics Creation Tools"
```

**NOTE:** To make the GUI permanent between reboots you'll need to change your runlevel to 5. Open this file: `/etc/inittab using a text editor and change the following line:

```
id:3:initdefault:
```

To:

```
id:5:initdefault:
```

#### References

- [Add GNOME to a CentOS Minimal Install](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Linux/LINUX_AddGNOMEToCentOSMinimalInstall.shtml)

Comment: I tried that and got "No packages in any requested group available to install or update".  "sudo gdm" still just hangs.  Thanks,

Comment: @OtagoHarbour - you might want to confirm the list of groups that I've provided matches existing group names. You can use `yum grouplist`.

Comment: "Desktop" and "Desktop Platform" are both on the list when I do that.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

On my minimal CentOS 7 I did: `sudo yum -y groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"`
and then `startx` and everything work fine.

you can do `yum groups list` to check what group are available.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem with CentOS 7 Minimal install,** i figured it had something to do with the session but the gnome session was already installed with the `gnome-desktop3` package.

**This worked for me:**

I ended up **installing the package `gnome-session-xsession`**  which was not installed by the `gnome-desktop3` or any of the above mentioned groups. (I thought that gnome-session would already refer to the xserver but apparently it didn't)